# Can we say anything about the zeros and Galois group of the polynomial $(x^p-a)^{p^2}-p^{p^2+1}x+p^{p^2} a=0$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, galois-theory

Let $p$ be an *odd* prime number  and $\mathbb Q_p$ be the $p$-adic number field. Let $K=\mathbb Q_p(a)$ be the extension by $a=p^{\frac{p^2+1}{p^3-1}}$.

Consider the polynomial $f(x)=(x^p-a)^{p^2}-p^{p^2+1}x+p^{p^2}a \in K[x].$

- Given that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $K$ and its splitting field, say $F$, is of degree $\frac{p^3(p^3-1)}{2}$ i.e., $[F: \mathbb Q_p]=\frac{p^3(p^3-1)}{2}$.

> Can I find the zeros of $f(x)$ over its splitting field?

> Can we expect information about the Galois group of its splitting field? For example, whether the Galois is cyclic or not?

---

Since $p$ is an odd prime, $2 \nmid p^3$ but $2 \mid \frac{p^3-1}{2}$.

So $[F: \mathbb Q_p]=\frac{p^3(p^3-1)}{2}=p^3 \cdot \frac{p^3-1}{2} =[F:K][K: \mathbb Q_p]$.

For $p=3$, we get $\frac{(p^3-1)}{2}=13$. So this factor corresponds to a cyclic extension with Galois group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{13}$, while the other factor $[F:K]=p^3=27$. So the Galois group $G$ of the splitting field of $f(x)$  is isomorphic to one of the following: $$\mathbb Z_{13} \times \mathbb Z_{27}, ~ \mathbb Z_{13} \times \mathbb Z_{9} \times \mathbb Z_{3},~ \mathbb Z_{13} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_{3} \times \mathbb Z_3.$$
So there is a possibility $G$ is cyclic if $G=\mathbb Z_{13} \times \mathbb Z_{27}.$

But I cannot get any exact conclusion.

I am expecting the zeros of $f(x)$ to be "$p$ to the exponent type similar to $a$" up to multiplication by a unit of $\mathbb Q_p$.

Thanks